# Oracle SQL String search with no spaces and replace with space

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle table which has a column called `sql_query`. All the SQL queries are placed in this column for all the records in that table.

Now, I see many records which have NO SPACE before WHERE in WHERE clause. I need it because the field hits several web forms and I get a syntax error.

Ex:

```
Select * from haystackwhere id = 3;
```

How do find these kind of records and replace them with a space like this:

```
Select * from haystack where id = 3;
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to just use the `like` operation, assuming that your SQL queries are all simple (such as having a single `where` clause):

```
select *
from table t
where sql_query like '%where %' and sql_query not like '% where %';
```

You can readily turn this into an update:

```
update table
    set sql_query = replace(sql_query, 'where ', ' where ')
    where sql_query like '%where %' and sql_query not like '% where %';
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will look for any instances of the column that don't have the word 'WHERE' with a space before it.  Then, if the word WHERE exists in those records, it will update it to '(space) WHERE'

```
UPDATE Table
SET SqlQuery = REPLACE(SqlQuery, 'WHERE', ' WHERE')
WHERE SqlQuery NOT LIKE '% WHERE%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if your SQL queries do not have WHERE anywhere else in the query.

For example, if you have a field named WHERE_LOCATION in the query, this will not work.

To replace the SQL query directly:

`--YOUR QUERY:`

```
select replace(replace(replace('Select * from haystackwhere id = 3;',
```

'where', ' where '), 'WHERE', ' WHERE '), 'Where', ' Where ') from dual;

```
--If you have WHERE encoded as another case, E.G. wHere, modify appropriately.
```

To replace using PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR C1 IS SELECT SQL_FIELD_COLUMN FROM YOURTABLE;
    NEW_SQL VARCHAR(1000);
BEGIN
    FOR R1 IN C1
    LOOP
        --WILL NOT WORK IF SQL_FIELD_COLUMN CONTAINS COLUMNS NAMED WHERE_LOCATION, ETC.
        --REMEMBER TO Change replacements for other cases, E.G. wHere
        --
        NEW_SQL := replace(replace(replace(R1.SQL_FIELD_COLUMN, 
       'where', ' where '), 'WHERE', ' WHERE '), 'Where', ' Where ');

        --NOW UPDATE THE TABLE/S CONTAINING YOUR SQL
    END LOOP;
END;
```